# Why did my people reached go down?

Tags: support, user-profile

Yesterday my people reached was something above 520.  Why is it at 493? (I am talking about my Arqade profile not Arqade meta)

Comment: That's odd, perhaps one of your posts has been deleted.

Comment: @D.Va no I checked if I remember correctly none got deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [announcement for the 'people reached' stat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here):

> ... [It] counts views on the following:
>
> Questions
>
> - Non-deleted only
>
> Answers - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
> - Non-deleted AND
> - Score > 0 AND
> - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>   - In the top 3 answers OR
>   - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>   - Score at least 5 OR
>   - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

Your 'people reached' statistic must have gone down because one of your posts no longer meet the above criteria.

---

As a side note, you are currently at 526 people reached - so nothing may have happened at all.